# Removing Special Character from console to load a txt file

Tags: c#, console, special-characters

So my last Question was not clear, so here is my second try.

When I drag and drop my txt file into the console, I get a path like this:

```
"C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Bektas\Desktop\test\text1.txt"
```

How can I remove the `"` character automatically?

I have to delete this by hand before I save my path into a string...

Here's my code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String pfad;
        String pfad2;
        String speichern = "C:\\Dokumente und Einstellungen\\Bektas\\Desktop\\test\\ausgabe.txt";

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Pfad eingeben: ");
            pfad = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Pfad eingeben: ");
            pfad2 = Console.ReadLine();
            // Input
            List<String> data = File.ReadAllLines(pfad)
                .Concat(File.ReadAllLines(pfad2))
                .Distinct().ToList();

            // Processing
            data.Sort();

            // Output
            Console.WriteLine("Duplikate entfernt & sortiert:");
            data.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
            File.WriteAllLines(speichern, data.ToArray());

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Die Anwendung schlug fehl: {0}\t" + e.ToString());
        }

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

Comment: could you please specify your question? Where have you to delte the char?

Answer (score 3):

You could automatically remove `"` characters by doing something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Pfad eingeben: ");
pfad = Console.ReadLine();
if (pfad.StartsWith("\"") && pfad.EndsWith("\"")) {
    pfad = pfad.Substring(1, pfad.Length - 2);
}
```

Also, since you are doing this twice with `pfad` and `pfad2`, you should extract this code into a function to reduce code duplication:

```
private static string RemoveQuotes(string input) {
    if (input.StartsWith("\"") && input.EndsWith("\"")) {
        return input.Substring(1, input.Length - 2);
    } else {
        return input;
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args) {

  // ...

  Console.WriteLine("Pfad eingeben: ");
  pfad = RemoveQuotes(Console.ReadLine());

  Console.WriteLine("Pfad eingeben: ");
  pfad2 = RemoveQuotes(Console.ReadLine());      

  // ...
```

}

Answer (score 1):

`pfad = pfad.Replace("\"", "");` will replace all " with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If your "special string" is longer that one character do the following:

```
string replacedString = Regex.Replace(originalString, specialString);
```